# Why DocumentDbBotDataStore does not cause a deadlock?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, botframework

After the [announcement](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/12/19/bot-state-service-will-soon-retired-march-31st-2018/), that the out-of-the-box bot state management will be deprecated, Microsoft has provided [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-cosmosdb) explaining how to setup custom BotState data provider.

This is how I plug-in custom BotState provider according to the documentation:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    var uri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbUrl"]);
    var key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbKey"];
    var store = new DocumentDbBotDataStore(uri, key);

    Conversation.UpdateContainer(builder =>
    {
        builder.Register(c => store)
            .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
            .AsSelf()
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.Register(c => new CachingBotDataStore(store, CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy.ETagBasedConsistency))
            .As<IBotDataStore<BotData>>()
            .AsSelf()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    });
}
```

Now, if we take a look at `DocumentDbBotDataStore` constructor, which is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/6ceed6cff3e75dc9aed986f3012907105c038278/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/DocumentDbBotDataStore.cs#L72):

```
public DocumentDbBotDataStore(Uri serviceEndpoint, string authKey, string databaseId = "botdb", string collectionId = "botcollection")
    : this(new DocumentClient(serviceEndpoint, authKey), databaseId, collectionId) { }

public DocumentDbBotDataStore(IDocumentClient documentClient, string databaseId = "botdb", string collectionId = "botcollection")
{
    SetField.NotNull(out this.databaseId, nameof(databaseId), databaseId);
    SetField.NotNull(out this.collectionId, nameof(collectionId), collectionId);

    this.documentClient = documentClient;
    this.databaseId = databaseId;
    this.collectionId = collectionId;

    CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    CreateCollectionIfNotExistsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

You can see that asynchronous methods `CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync` and `CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync` are called synchronously using `GetAwaiter()
.GetResult()` calls which can cause deadlocks. [Here is](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/6ceed6cff3e75dc9aed986f3012907105c038278/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/DocumentDbBotDataStore.cs#L207) how the implementation of these two methods looks like:

```
private async Task CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await documentClient.ReadDatabaseAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(databaseId));
    }
    catch (DocumentClientException e)
    {
        if (e.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            await documentClient.CreateDatabaseAsync(new Database { Id = databaseId });
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is not even `ConfigureAwait(false)` being called to reduce the risk of deadlocks.

**Question:**

How is it possible that this setup has never caused deadlocks?

Comment: I would say there is no SynchronizationContext

Answer (score 0):

**Application_Start** is guaranteed to only be called once, for the lifetime of the application domain: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx#Anchor_1

It is safe to create the database, and collection in **Application_Start**.